# Query Content Resolver get all logs between two days

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I want to create a query to a `ContentResolver` that will return all the call logs (`name`, `number`, `photo`) between a specified time, but it needs to be sorted by the number of counts.
A MySQL query would look like:

```
SELECT count(*) as counts, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
  CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_ID
FROM calls
WHERE CallLog.Calls.DATE > '2016-02-02' AND CallLog.Calls.DATE < '2016-02-04'
GROUP BY CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME order by counts DESC;
```

This is how I made the query, but I need also the `group by` and the `order`:

```
Cursor cur = .getContentResolver()
  .query(callUri, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", whereValue, null);
```

Can you please help me to add `group by` name and `order by` the count of each item?

Comment: order by is the last parameter .... group by is not supported via this interface ... but you can try to use projection with  `{ BaseColumn._COUNT, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER }` (instead null as second parameter) and maybe implementation of the CallLogs's ContentProvider would take care about adding group to the query

Comment: Thank you for your response! I want tot try this, but i don't know what is BaseColumn._COUNT